# Rank by Date and Qty in SQL

Tags: sql, rank

I have a table called `SALES`, with `Person`, `Date` and `Qty`.

```
Person  Date       Qty
Jim     2016-08-01  1
Jim     2016-08-02  3
Jim     2016-08-03  1
Bob     2016-08-01  5
Bob     2016-08-02  1
Bob     2016-08-03  6
Sheila  2016-08-01  4
Sheila  2016-08-02  0
Sheila  2016-08-03  2
```

I'm looking to rank by qty for each date, with the following output:

```
Person  Date       Qty    Rank
Bob     2016-08-01  5      1
Sheila  2016-08-01  4      2
Jim     2016-08-01  1      3
Jim     2016-08-02  3      1
Bob     2016-08-02  1      2
Sheila  2016-08-02  0      3
Bob     2016-08-03  6      1
Sheila  2016-08-03  2      2
Jim     2016-08-03  1      3
```

How do I use the Rank Function here?

Comment: what if there's a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SALES TABLE(
Person NVARCHAR(50),
[Date] NVARCHAR(50),
Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Jim','2016-08-01',1)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Jim','2016-08-02',3)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Jim','2016-08-03',1)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Bob','2016-08-01',5)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Bob','2016-08-02',1)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Bob','2016-08-03',6)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Sheila','2016-08-01',4)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Sheila','2016-08-02',0)
INSERT INTO @SALES VALUES('Sheila','2016-08-03',2)



SELECT * ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [Date] 
ORDER BY Qty DESC) N'Rank' 
FROM @SALES 
GROUP BY [Date], Person, Qty
ORDER BY [Date] ASC,Qty DESC
```

Result
[image]

==============================================
Update: select top 2 for each day

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT * ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [Date] 
    ORDER BY Qty DESC) N'Rank' 
    FROM @SALES 
    GROUP BY [Date], Person, Qty
    ) AS NewTable
WHERE NewTable.Rank  < 3
```

Result
[image]

NOTE:
You can't use `WHERE Rank < 3` directly, because `WHERE` clause is before `SELECT` statement, `WHERE` clause can't recognize `Rank` column. You have to use subquery.

Comment: That works well.  How would I limit the output to just the Top 2 for each day?

Comment: I updated my answer, now it can select top 2 for each day